# How to download files from jFrog repository using curl command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, curl, artifactory

I'm trying to download .EAR file from jFrog artifactory using curl command and save it on to the server.

```
curl -k -b "/appl/webappl/server/cookie.txt" "https://jfrog.dev.com/ui/v1/download?repoKey=key&path=path%252Ffile.ear" -o "/appl/webappl/server/file.ear"
```

Questions:

1. How to select this specific url from dev tools on browser *"https://jfrog.dev.com/ui/v1/download"*
2. How to choose repoKey and the path
3. Why can't we use direct url to the file

Answer (score 3):

I have a repository called maven-local, and uploaded an ear file called test.ear under the path com/test/jfrog.

We can use the below `curl` command directly to download the file:

```
curl -u "user:password" -X GET https://myartifactory.jfrog.io/artifactory/maven-local/com/test/jfrog/test-test.ear -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -o test.ear
```

Comment: You are right, file can be downloaded using direct url to the file but how can we do this using repoKey and Path to the file, Any idea?

Comment: How can I download a folder?

Answer (score 1):

The below solution was worked for me.

```
curl -vk -u username:password/apikey -X GET 'https://repo_path/file_path/file_name' > file_name
```