# How to download the builds from JFrog repository using Java

Tags: javascript, java, devops, jfrog-cli, jfrog-container-registry

I'm very new to JFrog Artifact. People are using the Jfrog artifacts repository in one of my project to download the latest build for their testing activities.

Is there any way to download the build through *curl or programmatically* *(Java (OR) JS)*.

I haven't get any enough resource to perform hands on. I will start my direction based on this answers.

Comment: Java and JavaScript is different. How about change the tags?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73533419/2970947

Comment: We can get build info using the get build info REST API call: jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/build-info In case if you want to download build artifacts, you can follow the instructions provided in this article: jfrog.com/help/r/… Please do comment if you require any further details on this matter.